# CSS: dynamic min-height depending on resolution

Tags: header, footer, css

is it possible to calculate the difference between two divs in an css file? Goal is to set the height of the content div to the max height what is given between a fixed header and footer. For instance we have a header div with 25% height and a footer with 15% height both fixed. The room between for the content should always be filled out completely. So due to the fact that the gap will be variable depending which resolution is set up on the clients display, I need something like:

min-height = browserheight - (headerheight + footerheight)

so long...

Comment: If the header is 25%, and the footer is 15%, why can't you set the content to 60%?

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible in pure CSS. But you can try LESS/SASS. It is css-like languages that compiles to pure css.

http://lesscss.org/

```
@containerWidth : 1000px;
@contentWidth   : 800px;

.side {
   width : @containerWidth-@contentWidth;
}
```

But with values, that you get from browser it's more difficult.

For example browser width, or browser height. You can get this value in LESS by executing some javascript (it's possible in LESS).
But then your style will work, only if you attach .less files as your styles and use javascript compiler in `<script>` tag, that when page is loaded, makes from your less styles - css styles. But it's slow.

The better way to use LESS, is to edit code in your .less files, compile it to .css and insert pure css styles on website. But if you compile your styles server-side, browser height or width can't be obtained.

Answer (score 0):

CSS does not currently support calculated values.

There are some experimental new CSS features in the pipeline that will do this, which are currently winding their way through the standardisation process and just starting to appear in beta versions of Chrome, Firefox, etc. You could start experimenting with it now, but it will be a long time before it'll have sufficient real-world browser support that you can use it for a real site.

In the meanwhile, if you want to find out more about the CSS Calc() feature, take a look at the [Mozilla Developer's site](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/CSS/-moz-calc).

Old versions of Internet Explorer had a feature called `CSS Expressions`, which was also very similar in concept. However, it was never standardised, and is no longer supported.

So as things are today, standard CSS doesn't support this kind of thing.

The alternatives are to use a CSS pre-processor such as [LESS](http://lesscss.org/) or [SASS](http://sass-lang.com/). Both of these programs are attempts to extend the CSS syntax with programming-like features, in the absence of a pure CSS solution. You write your CSS using SASS or LESS syntax, and then convert it to standard CSS before uploading it to your site.

These may give you what you're looking for, though as the end result is still standard CSS, you will still be unable to do dynamic calculations with them.

Hope that helps.